# Whitelabel Error Page even though application.properties looks fine

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

Even though my `application.properties` looks fine when I go to
http://localhost:8080/h2-console I still get the whitelabel error page

My `application.properties` :

```
server:
    port: 8080
Spring:
    h2:
      console:
        enabled: true
        path: /h2-console
        onsole.settings.trace: false
        scpring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others: false
    datasource:
        url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
        username: sa
        password:
        driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    jpa:
        show-sql: true
        defer-datasource-initialization: true
        database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Answer (score 0):

White label errors occur when you don't have a mapping for `/error`. Check if you have the `/h2-console` route defined in one of your controller methods. If you have ensure all your classes are on the same folder level or deeper as your main class to ensure component scanning actually finds your classes.